# how to move a line Shape object

Tags: easeljs

Using EaselJS 1.0 I want to move a line. I can get this to work setting the x and y by incrementing and decrementing, but not by setting x and y directly to numbers. IOW - line.x++; works, but line.x = 300; does not work. The code editor here seems cranky, so in case I fail inserting code see two versions running online here:

http://www.clarksoncs.com/Gettysburg/testMovingLineAlt.html

http://www.clarksoncs.com/Gettysburg/testMovingLine.html

In the init function:

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
stage = new createjs.Stage("canvasOne");

line.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3);
line.graphics.beginStroke(color);
line.graphics.moveTo(300, 400);
line.graphics.lineTo(startX, startY);
line.graphics.endStroke();
stage.addChild(line);

stage.update();
```

in the tick event:

```
//Run these two lines: Expected = line moves right and up. Actual = line moves right and up AND GETS LONGER.
line.x++;
line.y--;

/*
Run these two lines: Expected = line appears centered at 600,600. Actual = line is not visible. Check debugger, x and y are set to 600.
line.x = 600; 
line.y = 600;
*/

stage.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here might be that you are confusing the graphics coordinates with the line's position.

The line you are making is at [0,0]. Its registration point has not moved. You are then drawing the line from the *internal coordinates* of [300,400] to wherever your `startX` and `startY` are. The line position doesn't change because of the internal graphics coordinates.

My guess is that when you set the line to `x=600`, it is not visible because your graphics are now off-stage. The line position will be 600, but the line graphics start at 300 on top of that.

Here is a quick fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/b01tsw42/1/

```
var line = new createjs.Shape();
line.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3);
line.graphics.beginStroke("#ff0000");
line.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
line.graphics.lineTo(300, 400);
line.graphics.endStroke();
stage.addChild(line);

stage.x = 300; // sets the graphic container to x=300
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm not understanding the difference between line position and graphics coordinates. Is this explained in the docs somewhere? Bottom line, how do I set the line's position? Do "internal graphics coordinates" correspond to a property on the Shape object? Or some other object?

Comment: "Sort of sounds like" the Shape object and the line are not the same? Certainly the coordinate systems don't seem to...(sorry...) ...coordinate.

Comment: The Line is a shape, which is a display object that knows how to draw a set of graphics instructions. You can set the X/Y position of any display object directly as you tried in your first example. But think of the graphics coordinates of instructions as relative 0. For example if you wanted to draw a square that's registration point was in the middle, you could draw it at -25,25, with 50 as the width/height. The "registration point" is where the graphics draws from, and how it transforms (rotates, skews).

Comment: I took your line example, made the graphics a square, offset the coordinates of one of them, and then rotated them to provide an example. https://jsfiddle.net/bce2nwjz/

Answer (score -1):

Thanks! I think the easiest way to move a line shape is probably to put the line in a bitmap, and move the bitmap.